# SFTP Connection customization / parameterization

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to have a pipeline that read some parameters from database and pass those to the dataSet and then to the linked service. The scenario is a sFTP connection to pickup files and I want to be able to pass the values for the connection.

I posted a question in azure-docs and somehow I was able to go only half of the way. - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/52385

I was able to put parameters in the SFTP connection (and executing the test, passing the values for the parameteres, works fine). The problem is when I try to use that connection in a dataset. Using a csv dataset, I don't get the option to pass to the linked service the connection details/parameters.

- Host
- Port
- User name
- Password (already allows to retrieve from AKV)

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance,
Manuel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a parameterized SFTP linked service by using below JSON code. This sample has parameterized Host, Port, UserName properties.

```
{
    "name": "Sftp_LinkedServiceParameterized",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "HostParameter": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "defaultValue"
            },
            "PortParameter": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "defaultValue"
            },
            "UserNameParameter": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "defaultValue"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "Sftp",
        "typeProperties": {
            "host": "@{linkedService().HostParameter}",
            "port": "@{linkedService().PortParameter}",
            "skipHostKeyValidation": true,
            "authenticationType": "Basic",
            "userName": "@{linkedService().UserNameParameter}",
            "encryptedCredential": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXencryptedCredentialXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    }
}
```

After creating the linked service, publish it first and then refresh. Now create a data set in which you want to use this Linked service. You will have to create dataset parameters for Host, Port and UserName properties and map them to Linked service properties in the Dataset connection tab as below.

Below sample shows input pipeline parameters (Host, Port, UserName):

[image]

Below image show dataset parameters (Host, Port, UserName)

[image]

Below image show how to map Dataset parameters to Linked Service parameters (Host, Port, UserName)

[image]

Below image shows how to map input pipeline parameters to dataset parameters.

[image]

This way you will be able to pass Linked service parameter values from `source/pipeline parameters -> dataset parameters -> linked service parameters`

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @KranthiPakala-MSFT and by the good description of the steps. Best Regards, Manuel

Comment: What about parameterizing the password?